# Given the following code (in GCC 4.3) , why is the conversion to reference called twice?

Tags: c++

Given the following code (in GCC 4.3) , why is the conversion to reference called in both cases?

```
class A { };

class B {
public:
  operator A() {}
  operator A&() {}
};

int main() {
  B b;
  (A) b;
  (A&) b;
}
```

http://ideone.com/d6iF8

Comment: How can you tell from that code which conversion(s) is/are being called? Are you stepping through in the debugger? Do you have optimization enabled?

Comment: @MarkB see http://ideone.com/d6iF8

Comment: @MarkB or this one http://ideone.com/70RGi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is ambiguous and should not compile (it is *ill-formed* per 13.3.3:2).

lvalue-to-rvalue conversion has the same rank as identity conversion, so (per 13.3.3:1) there is no way to choose between them.

[Comeau C++](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout) (probably the most standards-compliant compiler) gives the following error:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 11: error: more than one user-defined conversion from "B" to
          "A" applies:
            function "B::operator A()"
            function "B::operator A &()"
    (A) b;
        ^
```

Here's the relevant text from the standard:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 13.3.3 Best viable function [over.match.best]
>
> [...] Given these deﬁnitions, a viable function F1 is deﬁned to be a better function than another viable function F2 [...]
>
> 2 - 
>   If there is exactly one viable function that is a better function than all other viable functions, then it is the
>   one selected by overload resolution; otherwise the call is ill-formed.

The definitions themselves are complicated, but there's two things to note with user-defined conversions:

First, the application of user-defined conversion as a conversion sequence is specified to decompose into a sequence `S_a - U - S_b` of a standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined conversion followed by another standard conversion sequence.  This covers all the cases; you can't have more than one user-defined conversion in a conversion sequence, and a standard conversion sequence can be the "identity conversion" i.e. no conversion required.

Second, when comparing user-defined conversion sequences the only part that matters is the second standard conversion sequence.  This is in 13.3.3:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 13.3.3 Best viable function [over.match.best]
>
> [...] a viable function F1 is deﬁned to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if [...]
>
> - the context is an initialization by user-deﬁned conversion (see 8.5, 13.3.1.5, and 13.3.1.6) and the
>     standard conversion sequence from the return type of F1 to the destination type (i.e., the type of the
>     entity being initialized) is a better conversion sequence than the standard conversion sequence from
>     the return type of F2 to the destination type.

and in 13.3.3.2:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank]
>
> 3 - Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of
>   the following rules applies: [...]
>
> - User-deﬁned conversion sequence U1 is a better conversion sequence than another user-deﬁned conversion sequence U2 if they contain the same user-deﬁned conversion function or constructor or aggregate
>     initialization and the second standard conversion sequence of U1 is better than the second standard
>     conversion sequence of U2.

So when comparing conversion sequences `U1 = (S1_a - U'1 - S1_b)` and `U2 = (S2_a - U'2 - S2_b)` the only thing that matters is the relative rank of `S1_b` and `S2_b`; the standard conversion sequences required to arrive at the parameter of the user-defined conversions do not matter.

So the possible conversion sequences for `(A) b`, requiring a conversion sequence yielding `B -> A`, are:

```
U1: B -> B [identity], B::operator A() [user-defined], A -> A [identity]
U2: B -> B [identity], B::operator A &() [user-defined], A & -> A [rvalue-to-lvalue]
```

Now, how do we rank standard conversion sequences?  The place to look is table 12 in 13.3.3.1.1, which specifies that lvalue-to-rvalue conversion has the same rank ("Exact Match") as identity conversion. So the two user-defined conversion sequences cannot be distinguished, and the program is ill-formed.

---

### Sidebar

What's the difference between 13.3.3 and 13.3.3.2 as regards ranking user-defined conversion sequences?

13.3.3 allows the compiler to distinguish between *different user-defined conversion operators*; 13.3.3.2 allows the compiler to distinguish between *different functions* that each require a user-defined conversion in their arguments.

So, in the code

```
struct A {
    operator int();
    operator float();
} a;
void f(int);
f(a);
```

13.3.3 applies and `A::operator int()` is selected over `A::operator float()`; in the code

```
struct A {
    operator int();
} a;
void f(int);
void f(double);
f(a);
```

13.3.3.2 applies and `void f(int)` is selected over `void f(double)`.  However in the code

```
struct A {
    operator int();
    operator float();
} a;
void f(int);
void f(double);
f(a);
```

even though 13.3.3 prefers `A::operator int() -> void f(int)` over `A::operator float() -> void f(int)` and `float -> double` over `int -> double`, and 13.3.3.2 prefers `int -> int` over `int -> double` and `float -> double` over `float -> int`, there is no way to distinguish between the `int -> int` and `float -> double` conversion sequences (because they contain neither the same user-defined conversion operator nor the same overload of `f`), and so the code is ill-formed.

Comment: clang trunk and gcc 4.7.1 allow the code, the comeau online front-end fails with the error your explanation would require.

Comment: @YamMarcovic without looking at the source of the compilers, I'd speculate that they're erroneously ranking identity conversion above lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  This seems to be a common problem; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465999/precedence-between-conversion-operators-in-c for an instance where compilers erroneously rank identity conversion above qualification conversion.

Comment: It would be nice, if you could give relevant quotes from the paragraphs you cite and explain what happens. Conversions are a mystery to me.

Comment: `A & -> A` [lvalue-to-rvalue]. I want to ask a simple question: Does `cv A& -> A` is [lvalue-to-rvalue]` also?