# Why does user-defined conversion applied during the initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

The following code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B
{
    operator int()
    {
        return int();
    }
};

struct A
{
    A(int, int){ std::cout << "A(int, int)" << std::endl; }
};

A a({B(), B()});

int main()
{ 
}
```

and produces output:

```
A(int, int)
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6cebcdab3ce5609)**

But I can't get why? What the Standard says is:

> However, when considering the argument of a constructor or
>   user-defined conversion function that is a candidate by 13.3.1.3 when
>   invoked for the copying/moving of the temporary in the second step of
>   a class copy-initialization, by 13.3.1.7 when passing the initializer
>   list as a single argument or when the initializer list has exactly one
>   element and a conversion to some class X or reference to (possibly
>   cv-qualified) X is considered for the first parameter of a constructor
>   of X [...] only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered

So in our case we considered the argument of the constructor (it was `{B(), B()}`). More precisely, we passed initializer-list as a single argument (the second case in the rule I cited). Now, we need to convert the first element of the initializer-list (temporary of type `B`) to `int` and the only way to do that is to apply user-defined convertion (`B::operator int()`). But, as said at the end of rule that I cited ***only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences was considered***. Since, that code shouldn't work, it should throw the error like `A(int, int)` is not viable or sort of.

What's wrong. May be it's a bug?

Comment: Cannot find this quote in N4140. What draft and paragraph are you quoting?

Comment: @Columbo: C++11 13.3.3.1/4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinguishing between user-defined conversion sequences by the initial standard conversion sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555950/distinguishing-between-user-defined-conversion-sequences-by-the-initial-standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording was defective and changed with C++14. Now [[over.best.ics]/4 reads](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#4)

> However, if the target is
>
> - the first parameter of a constructor or
> - […]
>
> and the constructor or user-defined conversion function is a candidate
>   by
>
> - 13.3.1.3, **when the argument is the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization**,
> - 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 (in all cases), or
> - the second phase of 13.3.1.7 when the initializer list has exactly one element, and the target is the first parameter of a
>     constructor of class `X`, and the conversion is to `X` or reference to
>     (possibly cv-qualified) `X`,
>
> user-defined conversion sequences are not considered. [ *Note:* These
>   rules prevent more than one user-defined conversion from being applied
>   during overload resolution, thereby avoiding infinite recursion. *—
>   end note* ]

The conversion of `B()` to `int` is not covered by this - the bold phrase only appertains to the binding of a reference to a temporary during copy-initialization. 
However, [Clang rejects this sample code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3428da2ca364cb1d) according to the above:

```
class A;

struct B
{
    operator A();
};

struct A
{
    A(A const&){}
};

A a{B()};
```